# slice and rearrange long skinny image to fit on screen

Tags: linux, imagemagick, crop, image-conversion, graphviz

I have many images, each roughly 10000 x 40 pixels, visualizing graphs that are mostly chains with a few spurs and other "decorations." (They're made by piping OpenFST's `fstdraw` through Graphviz's `dot`).

From the command line, how can I automatically brute-force rearrange one of these skinny images to readably fit on a 1920x1080 screen?  For instance, split the image into pieces at most 1920 pixels long, and then stack them vertically.

Something using ImageMagick's `convert -crop` in a loop?

Here's what fails:

- Replacing `dot` with one of its sisters `neato`, `fdp`, etc.  At
  least `fdp` outputs a non-skinny image, but only because the skinny
  graph randomly twists and overlaps like a frickin'
  chromosome.  The image is still mostly white, the labels are
  unreadably tiny, and the structure is just a squiggle.
- Adding the option `ratio=1` to `dot`'s input merely pads 10000x40 to
  10000x10000.

Answer (score 1):

Because 10000/1920 rounds up to 6, split the input into 6 pieces left-to-right, and glue them back together top to bottom.  Instead of using 6 intermediate files, use a format which holds multiple images (tiff is much faster than gif), and stdin and stdout.

`convert in.png -crop 6x1@ +repage tiff:- | convert tiff:- -append out.png`